# why does all of my background images not display

Tags: html, css

I have a div and I want that div to only have a background images, I have set the background in the css and have given it a height but for some reason it won't all display not matter what I set the right to.

Here is my code

```html
<div id="container">

    <div id = "church">


<a href="church.php"><img src="images/church.png"alt="church"/></a>



<h2>Come to Church</h2>

<p>We would love to meet you! Find out what's happing each Sunday and how to get here.</p>

    </div>


        <div id = "whatson">

<a href="whatson.php"><img src="images/whatson.png"alt="church"/></a>

<h2>What's On?</h2>

<p>Find out what we have going on within our church and why not come along.</p>


</div>

        <div id = "getintouch">

<a href="contact.php"><img src="images/getintouch.png"alt="church"/></a>

<h2>Get In Touch</h2>

<p>Have a question? why not get in touch</p>

</div>
</div>


<div id = "podcast">



</div>
```

Here is my css

```css
#podcast {

    background-image: url("images/iStock_000033667452_Large.jpg");
    background-position: 0px 350px;
     background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 800px 575px;
    height: 500px;
}


#church
{
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 200px;
   float: left;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

#whatson

{
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

#getintouch

{
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Comment: remember that `url()` in CSS is relative to the location of the css. if that css is in an external file, and in a different directory than the html, then your urls are incorrect. it'd have to be `url(../whatever/...)`.

Comment: my url is correct as part of the images shows but not all of it and it doesn't show no matter what i set the height to

Comment: Hard for us to tell because your snippet doesn't work.  When you say "doesn't show all" can you be more descriptive in how it's cutting off?

Comment: it shows only haft of the images and not the full image

Comment: background-size: contain; or background-size: cover;

Answer (score 0):

It works for me? I'm guessing your not calling the URL correctly. Do you have a link to the site?

```css
#podcast {

    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/600x300&text=placehold.it+rocks!");
    background-position:50%;
    background-size:cover;
    height: 500px;
}


#church
{
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 200px;
   float: left;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

#whatson

{
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

#getintouch

{
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

    <div id = "church">


<a href="church.php"><img src="images/church.png"alt="church"/></a>



<h2>Come to Church</h2>

<p>We would love to meet you! Find out what's happing each Sunday and how to get here.</p>

    </div>


        <div id = "whatson">

<a href="whatson.php"><img src="images/whatson.png"alt="church"/></a>

<h2>What's On?</h2>

<p>Find out what we have going on within our church and why not come along.</p>


</div>

        <div id = "getintouch">

<a href="contact.php"><img src="images/getintouch.png"alt="church"/></a>

<h2>Get In Touch</h2>

<p>Have a question? why not get in touch</p>

</div>
</div>


<div id = "podcast">



</div>
```

Comment: Bit leat someone already helped me fix it as you should have seen in the comments above